# How to import M# IDE generated models to Zebble for Xamarin - Cross platform solution

Tags: xamarin, shared-project, xamarin-zebble, zebble, m#

I started developing a project with M#(4.8.333) IDE and now I have a Domain project which I need to add to Zebble solution **Shared Project**.

How can I use this M# generated classes in Entities and DAL folder with Zebble mobile projects (UWP ,Android ,..) and still have the ability to change the and modify the project with M# if needed?

Should I manually copy paste the related **Entities** and **DAL classes** to this shared project or should I add the **existing** files directly to shared project, but it gives a few errors.

I knew this was not the correct way, but for sake of learning and understanding the project structure I started resolving the issues by adding the generated files to shared project and actually it creates a copy of them and then compile errors by

- replacing all  MSharp.framework namespaces with Zebble.framework
- replacing some customize exceptions with simple exceptions
- replacing SqlDataProvider with SQLiteDataProvider
- removing Aggregate function in DAL classes
- changing  ValidationResult signature and adding ValidationResult Parameter

  `protected override void ValidateProperties(ValidationResult result)`

I also know that DAL codes do not needs to be in the shared project except for local cache mechanism for persisting data temporarily but I want to know more about it and use it like the sample Contact DAL classed with SQLiteDataProvider in the template.

What is the best possible way to use M# IDE in Zebble for Xamarin -
    Cross platform solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that.

As it's explained in this video you should always keep your client side (mobile) model separate from the server side model:
http://zebble.net/docs/web-api-part-3-server-vs-client-domain-model

There are 4 main reasons which are explained in that video.

Comment: very well .I watched that video, but because I was asked to use M# and I saw sample zebble Contact entity was generated with all M# properties and caching , I thought that there should be some way of doing it.  So that generated template classes in App.Domain.Entities and DAL folders are used only for demonstrating SQLiteDataProvider usages